# Why are there gaps between rects in a D3 linechart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a slightly modified example of the following linechart: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245

Here's my JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rQ4xE/

**The goal** is to have blocks of background color different for periods of time. Changing color will not be difficult. However..

**Problem** is the gaps of different sizes between rects. I suspect this is because coordinates for the line path are decimal and something gets messed up when calculating the width for rects.

**My question is** what would be a good way to draw the background rects so that there are no gaps in between?

[image: Note the gaps between grey background blocks]

This is how I add the rects:

```
  svg.append("g").selectAll("rect")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("class", "area")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date) })
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("width", function(d, i) {
        not_last = i < data.length - 1;
        return not_last ? (x(data[i+1].date)-x(d.date)) : 0;
      })
      .attr("height", height);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have found a more elegant solution.

The issue can be solved by specifying to the scale to round the numbers to the nearest integer. That can be done by using scale.rangeRound which also sets the scale's interpolator to d3.interpolateRound.

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-linear_rangeRound

I changed this code:

```
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
```

to this:

```
var x = d3.time.scale().rangeRound([0, width]);
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HcC9z/2/

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a float issue in your x-coordinates and your widths. Try to round both of them.

```
svg.append("g").selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "area")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return Math.floor(x(d.date)) })
  .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("width", function(d, i) {
    not_last = i < data.length - 1;
    return not_last ? (Math.floor(x(data[i+1].date))-Math.floor(x(d.date))) : 0;
  })
  .attr("height", height);
```

**EDIT**
Here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rQ4xE/3/

Comment: My bad, it works! Thx, I'll play around with it a bit and accept if no one posts a better solution.

Comment: I'm just wondering if there is a way to make the scale return integers for pixels rather than decimal numbers. This would solve the problem wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, you could use the quantize scale, but you would then have to compute an array of discrete output values for it, so that would be an overkill. I think that since you just want to display some zones, rounding a bit the coordinates is not really a problem. I mean, what you want is to display a continuous set of zones, right ?